# Angular 2 change image src attribute

Tags: angular

Assuming I have the following code:

```
<img [src]="JwtService.characterImage(enemy)" 
        class="{{enemy.status}}"
    (click)="sidenav.toggle();" style="cursor:pointer">
```

How I can change this img `src` asttribute from my components `.ts` file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a imgSrc in your component

```
class Component {
 constructor(jwtService: JwtService) {
     this.imgSrc = JwtService.characterImage(enemy);
 }
}

<img [src]="imgSrc" 
        class="{{enemy.status}}"
    (click)="sidenav.toggle();" style="cursor:pointer">
```

Comment: I was wondering if there is any way to access the img `src` attribute without declaring a new variable

Comment: is it possible to change img src using reference on change event of radio button in Angular2 not in .ts file? @Piyush

Comment: @Piyush.kapoor what if img tag in ngFor and I need get image from server by passing name of the file

Answer (score 3):

You could pass a reference of your  tag using $event and change it's attribute from your typescript code.

```
<img (click)="functionInTypeScript($event.target)">
```

Or if you want to change something in image tag on another event you could do it like this

```
<img #image>
<button (click)=functionInTypeScript(image)>
```

and then simply access in typescript code like this

```
functioninTypeScript(image:any) {
   image.src='path to new image';
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. 
With #image you get an ElementRef object, not a direct access to the DOM object ... but of course, the ElementRef has a "nativeElement" property as an accessor to the DOM object.

So, it would be:
image.nativeElement.src = "path to new image";

Answer (score 3):

Typescript:

```
getImage(image: any, time: string) {
    const t1 = '06:00';
    const t2 = '18:00';
    if (time >= t1 && time < t2) {
      return ('/images/morning.png');
    } else {
      return ('/images/evening.png');
    }
  }
```

HTML :

```
  <img [src]="getImage(this,bettrainList.departureTime)" width="25">
```