# Angular interpolation creates a literal content

Tags: angular

I am trying to use interpolation to pass value of `src` attribute of `img` HTML element. However, this influences how the element is rendered, the element is rendered as a literal.

```
<div *ngFor="let tour of tours" class="col-md-4 tour-tile">
  <div class="tour-tile-inner">
    <div class="top-bar">{{ tour.name }}</div>
    <img class="myimage img-responsive thumbnail" src="{{"/images/tours/kutna-hora/tile.jpg"}}" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I tried also `src={{...}}` instead of `src="{{...}}"` with the same result. I do not know why the literal is rendered.

Comment: Not sure why you want to use interpolation in that case, but using inner single quotes should work: `src="{{'/images/tours/kutna-hora/tile.jpg'}}"`. The simple syntax would be ``src="/images/tours/kutna-hora/tile.jpg"``, without interpolation.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thank you, with single quote inside the curly brackets it is working. I tried to simplify the code, that is why there is only a string in the expression.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 change image src attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334010/angular-2-change-image-src-attribute)